# If a letter isn't pronounced but affects pronunciation of other letters, is it still 'silent'?

Tags: pronunciation, orthography, silent-letters

The 'e' in *paste* isn't pronounced on its own, but changes the pronunciation of the 'a'.

In that case, is the 'e' still referred to as silent?

Comment: silent but deadly

Comment: This is not a general reference question: it deals with a confusing aspect of English orthography that requires expertise to answer, and the good answer from John Lawler reflects that fact. Voting to reopen.

Comment: Why are the close voters silent on why? Voting to re-open. At least I would like to know the answer.

Comment: Well, yes, it's said to be "silent". However, there's is a school of thought that modifying the pronunciation is the very raison d'etre of "silent" letters. Exceptions are, where the word was originally pronounced with, and now without, the sound of the "silent" letter.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First, there's no international standard for letter silence, nor even a good definition.
It's not a technical term, but something that adults tell children
to keep them from asking "Why?", because the adults don't know the answer.

Second, that doesn't matter, since **all** letters are silent, anyway.
Letters are written; they are visual. They have no sound. At all.

Written language is just a way of representing spoken language, which is the real language.
You should get over the idea that letters are "pronounced", or not.
Letters are **written**, or not. [**Sounds**](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/modestproposal.pdf) are pronounced, or not.

Writing is just modern technology.  Modern compared to agriculture, anyway.
English spelling and writing and reading got frozen at Middle English,
which is a big reason why we have so much trouble spelling.

But saying a letter is "silent" is no help. As you point out, what that means isn't clear.

Comment: "Written language is just a way of representing spoken language" this is not true in general and not true in the case of the Latin language.

Comment: Written language is, most commonly, a way of representing spoken language _based on certain general rules and conventions_. One basic convention in alphabetic writing systems is that anything written should somehow reflect some part of the spoken item whose representation it is part of. It does make sense, didactically, to group those letters conspicuous for not aiding this representation at all together; the label ‘silent’ is perhaps not ideal, but it is at least well-established.

Comment: @Carlo_R., yes, it is true in general, and also for the Latin language. The written language is a representation of a language that was spoken before it was written. The fact that nearly no one now speaks (or writes!) the language natively does not change that fact. The only languages whose written forms are not abstract representations of their spoken forms are mechanical and programming languages, as well as music notes (even if you accept music as a language, written notes are an abstraction of something played/sung, not spoken).

Comment: [cont’d] And of course also some entirely artificial languages, such as what Classical Chinese was probably originally: a standardised, artificial hodgepodge of dialects, with a grammar and vocabulary that would not have been used in any living, spoken language, but only gathered for the specific purpose of written communication between officials throughout the country.

Comment: @Janus, sorry, I'm not a linguist, and what you and John say may be technically true. Nevertheless I think that when a language, originary in the form of spoken language, ends to have a written representation it doesn't evolve anymore, or, at least, its sligth evolution ends to became greatly influenced by its written representation. Of course, my considerations are the considerations of one that don't understand almost nothing of language.

Comment: @Carlo_R. Just a friendly note, my good fellow. You might want to soften your opinions just a tiny bit. There's a lot of room for discussion here, and the language is a rather flexible, debatable, slippery thing. We all appreciate your passion and interest, and keep it up! But go easy, too, okay? I might also point out that John Lawler is too humble to say this himself, but his expertise on the language is huge, to put it mildly. (I don't know Monsieur Jacquet, but it seems as if he also knows quite a heck of a lot, too.)

Comment: Indeed. Many would be amazed at the range of answers you get if you ask somebody what silent letters there are in words like *sheep*, *thistle*, or *troupe*.

Comment: @tchrist: Poor Carlo certainly makes a rod for his own back when he takes up cudgels against the likes of John and Janus here! But in my time at ELU it seems to me you're more in his camp than the "language is primarily a *spoken* phenomenon" position being advanced here (a position which I thoroughly endorse, being a crap speller myself, and unable to use punctuation consistently! :)

Comment: ...and if I *were* a professional writer myself (which obviously I'm not), I think I'd say spelling and punctuation are what you have copy editors for. In the *computer* languages I write, I take it for granted the compiler/syntax checker will take care of most of that donkey work for me.

Comment: @Janus Bahs Jacquet yes, John Lawler makes a good point, but from a pragmatic point of view how would those who want to improve pronunciation, as me and perhaps the OP, want to refer to this phenomenon? It has indeed a didactic usefulness. How would you else deal with it ?

Comment: As I said above, the label ‘silent letter’ is perhaps not linguistically ideal, but it works fine for didactic purposes when helping learners of a language separate letters that do not reflect any spoken counterpart, from the ones that do.

Comment: Yup. As long as it's localized. "The first _D_ in _Wednesday_ is silent." But there are problems, even there. How about "The _G_ in _singer_ is silent, but not the _G_ in _finger_"?  Or "The _H_ in _chasm_ is silent, but not the _H_ in _chastity_"?

Answer (score 5):

Yes, because that's the definition of a [silent](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/american/silent) letter:

> a silent letter is a letter in a word that has no sound when you say
>   the word but that must be used when the word is spelled or written

Comment: That 'definition' says nothing about its influence on pronunciation. How then can this answer the question? Prof thinks there's no such definition in the first place.